# How to replace character ' " ' randomly repeated in a string with alternating characters ' “ ' and ' ” ' (python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, loops

I am trying to replace any normal straight quotations (") in a given string with sets of curved open  and  closed quotations (“ and ”). This would mean the first, third etc "s would be replaced with “, and the second, fourth etc "s would be replaced with ”.

I have tried finding the index of the first quote, creating a splice up to it, and replacing all " in that splice with the “. I have followed that by creating a splice from this new quotes index+1 to the end and replacing all " with ”. The thing is, I am not going to be sure of the length or number of "s in the string provided, and so need to figure out a way to loop some sort of system like this.

This works to only convert a string with 2 quotes properly:

```html
def convert_quotes(text):
    '''(str) -> str
    Convert the straight quotation mark into open/close quotations.
    >>> convert_quotes('"Hello"')
    '“Hello”'
    >>> convert_quotes('"Hi" and "Hello"')
    '“Hi” and “Hello”'
    >>> convert_quotes('"')
    '“'
    >>> convert_quotes('"""')
    '“”“'
    >>> convert_quotes('" "o" "i" "')
    '“ ”o“ ”i“ ”'
    '''
    find=text.find('"')
    if find != -1:
        for i in text:
            #first convert first found " to “
            text1 = text[:find+1]
            replace1=text1.replace('"','“')
            text2 = text[find+1:]
            replace2=text2.replace('"','”')
            text=replace1+replace2
            return text
```

As seen in my docstring, '"Hello" should become “Hello”, but '" "o" "i" "' should become “ ”o“ ”i“ ”.

Comment: You could maybe iterate through your string and store the indexes of all occurrences of " in a list and then replace all evens with the “ and odd indexes with ” ?

Comment: This would be the most ideal way for me to do it as I have not technically learned import re and would be able to use enumerate? My issue is that they dont all technically have even indexes if open and odd if closed and vice versa. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: for the questions sake I would replace the quites with `(` and with `)` on smaller screens the difference is difficlut to see.

Comment: @sarahsss, you could first find the indexes of " and store them in a list. So you'll have something like indexes = [12, 17, 29, 35]. You can then iterate through this indexes list  with a for loop (something like... for i in xrange(len(indexes)) and check if the current iteration is even or odd (if i % 2 == 0 -> even). If even... you can replace that index with “ and if odd, replace with ” . Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the re.sub function.
I'll use parenthesises for better readability, just replace them with your quotes.

```
import re

s = """
sdffsd"fsdfsdfdsf fdsf<s" fgdgdfgdf " gfdgdfgd" gdfgdfgdf"
bla re bla
dfsfds " fdsfsdf " fsdfsd "
and the final odd " is here
"""

def func(match): # function for to be called for each sub() step
    return("(" + match.group()[1:-1] + ")")

rex  = re.compile(r'"[^"]*"') # regular expression for a quoted string.

result = rex.sub(func, s) # substitute each match in s with func(match)
result = result.replace('"', '(')  # take care of last remaining " if existing
print(result)
```

The output would be:

```
sdffsd(fsdfsdfdsf fdsf<s) fgdgdfgdf ( gfdgdfgd) gdfgdfgdf(
bla re bla
dfsfds ) fdsfsdf ( fsdfsd )
and the final odd ( is here
```

A second solution without using the re module:

```
s = """
sdffsd"fsdfsdfdsf fdsf<s" fgdgdfgdf " gfdgdfgd" gdfgdfgdf"
bla re bla
dfsfds " fdsfsdf " fsdfsd "
and the final odd " is here
"""

while True:
    if not '"' in s:
        break
    s = s.replace('"', '(', 1)
    s = s.replace('"', ')', 1)

print(s)
```

I didn't make any effort to make it efficient. 
The focus was on being simple.

Comment: Thank you so much! that does work. however, do you know of any method uses simpler loops, enumerate or string methods to find same result? I have not yet technically learned thee re.sub function :(

Comment: I added a second solution which just uses the replace() function and the
`in` operator to check whether a substring can be found in a string.
If you're not allowed to use it,  then you can use find() instead of `in`

The line would look like

`if s.find('"') == -1: break`

Comment: Thank you so much! this is perfect. Is the logic that as long as there are " left in th string, theey will be replaced... but I'm wondering how it is exactly that it is done by alternating. The third character in the replace method I've not had explained yet?

Comment: yes this is the logic:

As long as there is at least one double quote in  the string I replace one (the first double quote found) with a "(" (note the `,1` parameter in the replace function, which means replace only the first `"` encountered.
Then the next double quote (if it is found) will be replaced with a ")".
<then the loop repeats if there is still at least one remaining `"`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to collect all locations with quotes, and then change the characters accordingly. This requires an intermediate list of characters (`s_list` below):

```
import re

s = '"Hi" and "Hello"'
s_list = list(s)

quote_position = [p.start() for p in re.finditer('"', s)]

for po, pc in zip(quote_position[::2], quote_position[1::2]):
    s_list[po] = '“'
    s_list[pc] = '”'

s = "".join(s_list)
```

Comment: you might add a comment, that list(s) converts the string s into a list of its letters. It is oc course what python does, but perhaps not everybody knows.
You could also remove the `import re` line

Comment: This will probably not work  if you have an odd number of quotes.
The original question shows (If I understood correctly) one case with an odd number of double quotes.